# Basic Autohotkey not evaluating variable

Tags: autohotkey

Trying to set Autohotkey command but it's not working, I've used this same script before but it's not working with version 1.1.24.05 of AutoHotKey.

```
local = http://lcl.
dev   = http://dev.
stage = http://stg.
prod  = https://www.
mywebsite1 = sitename1.com
mywebsite2 = sitename2.com

:*:lclmywebsite1::%local%%mywebsite1%{enter}
:*:devmywebsite1::%dev%%mywebsite1%{enter}
:*:stgmywebsite1::%stage%%mywebsite1%{enter}
:*:lclmywebsite2::%local%%mywebsite2%{enter}
:*:devmywebsite2::%dev%%mywebsite2%{enter}
:*:stgmywebsite2::%stage%%mywebsite2%{enter}
```

When I type stgmywebsite2 AutoHotKey returns %stage%%mywebsite2%

It's no different to what I have below but the above example doesn't seem to evaluate the variables. Any ideas?

```
:*:mye@::myname@somedomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample demonstrates using variable expansion within a hotstring:

```
local = http://lcl.
mywebsite1 = sitename1.com

:*:lclmywebsite1::
  SendInput %local%%mywebsite1%{enter}
  return
```

From the documentation for [Hotstrings](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm):

> Variable references such as %MyVar% are not currently supported within the replacement text. To work around this, don't make such hotstrings auto-replace. Instead, use the SendInput command beneath the abbreviation, followed by a line containing only the word Return.

Comment: It's working for me. I'm running the same version as you (v1.1.24.05). You might have other code interfering with this hotstring. Try right-clicking the autohotkey icon on your task bar and choosing "Edit this Script". Save and replace the contents of your default script with my sample code. Right-click the autohotkey icon again and choose "Reload this script." Open notepad and type `lclmywebsite1`.

Comment: I did have code interfering, my variables needed to be created at the top of the file but i added them after a bunch of other commands. thank you for your help